# how to show Vertical image with read onlyText box Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently I am showing images horizontally With the HTML below. Now I want to add a Read only textbox along side with each Image vertically.

```
<div>
    <span>Uploaded Images</span>
    <div id="appendImages" class="img-section">
        <ul class="img-list" style="float:left">
            <li style="float:left; padding:5px; width:20%;" class="img-list-item" ng-repeat="img in wa.listOfWorkAssignmentDoc track by $index">
                <!--<button type="button" class="ion-close-round"
                        ng-click="removeImage(img)"></button>-->
                <!-- <img ng-src="{{ img.selectedImage }}" />-->
                <img ng-src="{{imgUrl}}{{img.documentId}}" width="100%" />
                <input type="text" />
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` in your `li` style property

```html
<div>
  <span>Uploaded Images</span>
  <div id="appendImages" class="img-section">
    <ul class="img-list" style="float:left">
      <li style="display: flex; float:left; padding:5px; width:20%;" class="img-list-item" ng-repeat="img in wa.listOfWorkAssignmentDoc track by $index">
        <!--<button type="button" class="ion-close-round"
                                        ng-click="removeImage(img)"></button>-->
        <!-- <img ng-src="{{ img.selectedImage }}" />-->
        <img ng-src="{{imgUrl}}{{img.documentId}}" width="100%" />
        <input type="text" />
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  </div
```

Comment: will i get vertical images along textbox for each image